# Для чего служат параметры функции?

Tags: c++

Я так понимаю, там объявляются типы переменных. А также ссылки (указатели). А разве типы переменных нельзя объявить в теле функции, оставив параметры пустыми f() ? Объясните пожалуйста назначение параметров функций.

Comment: А вызывать как будете? `f()` - это что, `f(1)` или `f("Hello")` или `f(2,4,5,15)`? Вот есть функция `sqrt()` - квадратный корень. Как ей объяснить, что нам нужен корень именно из 2, а не 18 или 45?

Comment: То есть в скобках нет никаких параметров, переменные описаны в теле функции. Такое ведь тоже может быть, по сути.

Comment: Я пытаюсь с этим разобраться, зачем нужны параметры, по-этому прошу объяснить. чтоб вызывать функцию? Вроди-бы можно это делать по ссылке и по значению. Но также типы тоже указываются в параметрах.

Comment: Каким образом вы предлагаете  использовать функцию, скажем, длины строки `strlen`, если вы не будете передавать в эту функцию никаких параметров? Длину какой строки она будут вычислять?

Comment: Но длину строки, и все прочее касательно строки можно задать (определить и инициализировать) в теле функции. А вызов этой функции из функции main невозможен без параметров function() ? Скобки нельзя оставить пустыми? Извините, я новичок.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Параметры функции предназначены для общения функции с "внешним миром", т.е. с кодом, который вызвал эту функцию.

Значения параметров внутри функции - это ни что иное, как значения аргументов функции, предоставленные вызывающим кодом в точке вызова. Таким образом вы передаете информацию (аргументы) снаружи из точки вызова внутрь функции. Когда вы вызываете функцию `sqrt` с аргументом `25`

```
sqrt(25)
```

значение `25` передается внутрь функции `sqrt` через ее единственный параметр. Внутри функция `sqrt` будет знать, что ее попросили вычислить квадратный корень из `25`, Что она и сделает.

Также параметры функции могут использоваться для возвращения результатов работы функции обратно в вызывающий код.

Переменные, которые объявлены локально внутри функции никакой связи с вызывающим кодом не имеют и использоваться для связи с внешним миром не могут.

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: внешний мир - это вы наверное имеете ввиду функцию main, которая вызывает функцию sqrt

Comment: Не обязательно main. Функция double sqrt(double) может быть вызвана любой другой функцией, которая "понимает", что такое sqrt.

Answer (score 2):

В дополнение к ответу @AnT - то, о чем вы говорите, немного похоже - *но только похоже!* - на объявление функций в *старом* K&R C:

```
int max(a, b, с)
int а, b, с;
{
    /* ... */
}
```

Но - имена параметров все равно нужно указывать; только и того, что вы объявляете их типы позже. Если не указывать параметры вовсе - функция просто не будет знать, что ей вообще что-то передано, т.е. не будет понимать, с какой входной информацией работать. Можно, конечно, и так - через глобальные переменные, но это же ужас! например:

```
double sqrt_param;
double sqrt() { /* Вычисление квадратного корня из sqrt_param */ };

int main()
{
    sqrt_param = 25;
    cout << "sqrt(25) = " << sqrt() << endl;
    sqrt_param = 36;
    cout << "sqrt(36) = " << sqrt() << endl;
}
```

Comment: большое спасибо